# mongoose population, array entry without schema (Schema hasn't been registered)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, population

I have trouble with mongoose array population.
My two models/schemas looks like:

### Endpoint

```js
// create schema
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    interface: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "Devices.interfaces"
    },
    room: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Rooms"
    }
    //commands: []
});

// register model
mongoose.model("Endpoints", schema);
```

### Device

```js
// create schema
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    room: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Rooms"
    },
    interfaces: [{
        type: {
            type: String, 
            required: true, 
            enum: [
                "RS232", 
                "ETHERNET"
            ]
        },
        settings: {
            //..
        }
    }]

});

// register model
mongoose.model("Devices", schema);
```

When i want to populate over the endpoints interface, i get a **MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Devices.interfaces"** Error

### Documents (Device)

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "5d5c0b8268dcf72a24f3e9b9",
        "name": "Test - 1",
        "interfaces": [
            {
                "_id": "5d5c0b8268dcf72a24f3e9bb",
                "typ": "RS232"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d5c0b8268dcf72a24f3e9ba",
                "typ": "ETHERNET"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d5c0d1fd4fefd1708901d1b",
        "name": "Test - 2",
        "interfaces": [
            {
                "_id": "5d5c0d1fd4fefd1708901d1d",
                "type": "RS232"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d5c0d1fd4fefd1708901d1c",
                "type": "ETHERNET"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

### Documents (Endpoint)

```js
{
    "_id": "5d5c0bef68dcf72a24f3e9bc",
    "name": "Test - 1",
    "interface": "5d5c0d1fd4fefd1708901d1d",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The Array in my device document has a valid object-id, why is the query population not properly working ? How can i query the interface from my endpoint document without register another schema/model ?

I tried to change the Array in my device schmea to a `mongoose.Schema`, but that didnt work. I get the same error.

EDIT: Query added.

```js
        const query = model("Endpoints").findOne({
            _id: "5d5c0bef68dcf72a24f3e9bc"
        });

        query.populate([ { path: 'interface', populate: [] } ]);

        query.exec((err, doc) => {
          // do something
        });
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your query?

Comment: I edited the post & added the query

Comment: Unfortunately not, the error persists

Comment: Your `ref` in `Endpoints` schema should point to the model but `Devices.interfaces` is not a model.

Comment: I know, thats excatly how it should be. I dont want/need a Interface schema/model.
The entrys in ```Device.interfaces``` got an _id, so they schould retrievable with it

Comment: can u show the code of index.js